# How to submit xml data to a web site?

Tags: xpages

I am using a third party to process transactions.  They have an api that says XML content should submitted via an HTTP POST variable named “XML”.

I know how to create the xml, but not sure how to post it to their site.  They have a destination url. Can you tell me how to do the Post to their site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to carefully check. Usually you just post XML to an URL. However in this case (indicated by the variable name) it seems that a (typically only used for html forms)  form post is needed.

The easiest way is to create a html form with that one field, something like this:

```
  <form method="post" action="http://their url" name="payload">
     <input type="hidden" id="XML" name="XML" />
  </form>
```

Then you can fill the field with your XML and do a payload.submit()

Let us know how it goes

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Wissel.  I new it had to be simple, I've never had to do something like this.

Comment: Sigh. 7 or 8 years ago, I had this extensive LotusScript agent that would format and post some CXML to OfficeDepot for ordering toner. Sadly, it never went into production. Your solution is sooooo much simpler! XPages rocks!

Comment: Stepen, I do have one question for you.  If I am in an existing xPages application where would I put the code you suggested?  For example, I have a page that shows the user a list of costs they selected.  They user will enter their credit card information and when the click a button ( Pay Now ) I need to create and submit the xml to my 3rd party vendor handling the credit card transaction.  Can I put this code into the button or do I have to open another xPage?  Your thoughts?

Comment: Same page is fine, so you don't need to send their data to your server. And be good: use https

Comment: Yes, I will be using https for sure.  Sorry to be a pain, I have never done this before so I'm learning.  Can you tell me specifically where the from code can be placed?  Can I put it all in a button?

Comment: You can't put HTML into a button, just put it on the page. Make sure it doesn't nest (tell XPage not to generate a form). In your button you only call the JS function that then submits it